# Modified Quickhull algorithm for finding convex hulls

Tags: computational-geometry, convex-hulls

The quickhull algorithm described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quickhull#Algorithm) finds the furthers point from the line segment in step 3. I am having trouble reasoning about what would be the result if the algorithm just considered the maximum y-coordinate instead. I think it would still yield the correct answer just possibly with more points lying outside the triangle described in step 4. Is this reasoning correct? I also believe I read somewhere that points with the same x-coordinates are chosen by considering the maximum y-coordinate which might have pushed me to this conclusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Imagine that the point with max $y$ is actually the leftmost point. Then you get $0$ points in the upper part. But at the same time there could be many there (especially if your line is tilted very much).

Comment: So getting 0 points in the upper convex hull would necessarily result in an incorrect solution? Also, if it was the leftmost point, meaning it has minimum x-coordinate, wouldn't that point be selected to form the line segment initially?

Comment: @dreamin Yes, precisely. So you'll get a degenerate triangle (a line) if it also happens to be the topmost point. Note that the same could happen for the rightmost a bottom part. So then you'll be stuck with a line. It's not necessary that you get such a pathological case, but it goes to show that you have no guarantees how many points will end up outside the triangle.